# Is a 192.169.0.0/16 a private address range?

Tags: routing, ipv4

I know that 192.168.0.0/16 are adresses reserved for private networks. What about 192.169.0.0/16 addresses and other.. in 192.0.0.0/8. Are they routable in the "Internet" or are they also private?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These reserved IP-ranges for private networks are defined in [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918). 192.169.0.0/16 is not in them. You can verify using a WHOIS service that this /16 is divided into a number of smaller assignments to various networks.

Answer (score 6):

No it isn't. See RFC6890 for all Special-Purpose IP Address Ranges (IPv4 and IPv6)

Answer (score 3):

> What about 192.169.0.0/16?

This is valid address space, and the addresses are routable, they are NOT private.

> What about other addresses in 192.0.0.0/8?

You'd have to verify with WHOIS, some of the networks other than 192.168.0.0/16 within the 192.0.0.0/8 range are also private.

You could check anything you like in the future from just about an Linux distribution command line via the WHOIS tool:

```
whois 192.0.0.0/8
whois x.x.x.x/yy
```

Example of valid address space:

```
NetRange:       192.0.0.0 - 192.255.255.255
CIDR:           192.0.0.0/8
NetName:        NET192
NetHandle:      NET-192-0-0-0-0
Parent:          ()
NetType:        Early Registrations, Maintained by ARIN
OriginAS:
Organization:   Various Registries (Maintained by ARIN) (VR-ARIN)
RegDate:        1993-05-01
Updated:        2010-06-30
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-192-0-0-0-0

OrgName:        Various Registries (Maintained by ARIN)
OrgId:          VR-ARIN
Address:        3635 Concord Parkway, Suite 200
City:           Chantilly
StateProv:      VA
PostalCode:     20151
Country:        US
RegDate:        1993-05-01
Updated:        2011-09-24
Comment:        Address space was assigned by the InterNIC regardless of
Comment:        geographic region.  The registrations are now being maintained
Comment:        by various registries, and the in-addr.arpa delegations are
Comment:        being maintained by ARIN.
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/VR-ARIN
```

Example of private address space:

```
Internet Assigned Numbers Authority PRIVATE-ADDRESS-CBLK-RFC1918-IANA-RESERVED (NET-192-168-0-0-1) 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
Various Registries (Maintained by ARIN) NET192 (NET-192-0-0-0-0) 192.0.0.0 - 192.255.255.255
```

From [RFC1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) Section 3:

```
   The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) has reserved the
   following three blocks of the IP address space for private internets:

     10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
     172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
     192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

Answer (score 1):

192.168.0.0/16 is the only **private** address space in 192.0.0.0/8. 192.0.0.0/24 is used by IANA, 192.0.2.0/24 is reserved for documentation and examples, and 192.88.99.0/24 is for 6to4 anycast.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses
https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html

Comment: Actually, there are several ranges in the 192.0.0.0/8 that are not routed on the Internet: 192.0.2.0/24 (Test Net 1).

Comment: I'm surprised ARIN would get this wrong but you are right, at least according to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses

Comment: This is an IANA document: http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

> I know that 192.168.0.0/16 are adresses reserved for private networks.

Yes

> What about 192.169.0.0/16 addresses

Those are regular public IPv4 addreseses allocated to various networks.

> and other.. in 192.0.0.0/8. Are they routable in the "Internet" or are they also private?

Most of the block is regular public IPs but there are a number of special things in there. Special allocations are documented at http://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml

```
192.0.0.0/24 is reserved for IETF protocol assignments. 
  192.0.0.0/29 is reserved for clients of ds-lite 464xlat and similar
  192.0.0.8/32 is reserved as a dummy address for 4rd
  192.0.0.9/32 is an anycast address for "port control protcol" 
  192.0.0.170/32 and 192.0.0.171/32 are used for DNS64 discovery
192.0.2.0/24 is reserved for documentation, examples etc
192.31.196.0/24 is used for "AS112 Redirection Using DNAME"
192.52.193.0/24 is used for "Automatic Multicast Tunneling"
192.88.99.0/24 is used as an anycast prefix for 6to4 relays
192.168.0.0/16 is private use
192.175.48.0/24 is Direct Delegation AS112 Service
```